# underline chapter title number (only) in bookdown when split_by not used

Tags: r, bookdown

How to add the 3px line under the number of Chapter title as in:
https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/introduction.html
without underlining also the sections (1.1). Problem occurs when 
`split_by: section` is not used in _output.yml. (I do not want to split by sections)

```
#_output.yml
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  split_by: section #<- NOT HAVING THIS

#css
.level1 .header-section-number {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
}
```

Comment: That's controlled by the CSS, which you can see here: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/inst/examples/css/style.css. Look specifically at `.level1 .header-section-number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do that with:

```
.level1 .header-section-number {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
}

.level2 .header-section-number {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```